# Auto increment Identity column insert error

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

Ok, first off I have seen several questions on this issue. I have gone through just about all of them and none of the solutions prescribed worked for me.
I am using asp.net core 1.1.0 and SQL Server 2016. I am also using the code first approach. The following is my mappings for the table in question

```
public class TierMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Tier>
{
    public void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<Tier> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(a => a.TierID);
        builder.Property(a => a.TierID).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn<int>();
        builder.HasOne(a => a.Country)
            .WithMany(a => a.Tiers)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.CountryID);
    }
}
```

Below is the design view of the table in SQL Server:

When I create a new instance of a `Tier` object, all the properties except the `TierID` get some value (a random negative integer). So inserting into the database throws the following error

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Tiers' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

[image]

Below is the code the attempts to save the data

```
[HttpPost("AddTier")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddTier([FromBody]TierDataModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Response.AddApplicationError("Data is invalid ");
        return BadRequest();
    }

    Tier tier = new Tier();
    tier.TierName = model.TierName;
    tier.TierNo = model.TierNo;
    tier.CountryID = model.CountryID;
    _tierService.AddTier(tier);

    await _unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Try change this line:  builder.Property(a => a.TierID).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn<int>(); by:  builder.Property(a => a.TierID).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: So I run this command SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tiers ON in SQL Server Management studio and provided values for TierID still didnt work out. Strangely the random integer value remained ignoring my provided value for TierID. When I checked my migrations folder i had this in there: "TierID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn)". Hmmmmmm!! What  am I missing?

Comment: Why do you need to run that command?, to add an identity in a table it's simple like Id int not null identity(1, 1)

Comment: @H. Herz Because I wanted to see if I provide the data for the Id column it will still result in that same error and it did which i find very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Changing _dbSet.Attach(entity); to _dbSet.Add(entity); in my Repository Class solved the problem